# Using multiple log files but only one is actually working

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'm trying to use two log files for my app (access_log & error_log).
Here is how I set this up:

```
# setup logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

# access file logger
accesslog = logging.getLogger('simple_logger')
hdlr_1 = logging.FileHandler("C:\Users\xxx\code\log\access_log")
hdlr_1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
hdlr_1.setFormatter(formatter)
accesslog.addHandler(hdlr_1)

# error file logger
errorlog = logging.getLogger('simple_logger_2')
hdlr_2 = logging.FileHandler("C:\Users\xxx\code\log\access_log")    
hdlr_2.setFormatter(formatter)
errorlog.addHandler(hdlr_2)

# log access
accesslog.info('Process started') # this doesn't work
accesslog.error('Process started') # this works
```

When an error is thrown at some point I log it using:

```
errorlog.error("message") # this works
```

The messages logged with `.error()` are actually saved to the log files but not the ones logged with `info()`.

I added the `.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to the accesslog handler but still no success...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
hdlr_1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

becomes

```
accesslog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

and now it works. It's weird because according to the [python27 doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) it says that if you don't set the logging level it will be set by default to `NOTSET` meaning *all* message levels are processed but it seems it's not true.

Comment: Levels on loggers are not the same as levels on handlers. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow